# Mathematica 10 Graph issue

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Please try to evaluate this code in Mathematica 10.

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
g = RandomGraph[{12, 18}];
pt = GraphEmbedding[g];
convexhull = ConvexHull[pt];
Show[PlanarGraphPlot[pt, convexhull, ColorOutput -> Red], g,
Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point[#]} & /@ pt]]
```

[image]

Works perfectly fine on the version 9. What is this dynamic object showing up? Anybody got some explanation for this.

Comment: The graph doesn't have a layout.  In this case it gets shown like a summary box.  *Why* it doesn't have a layout I don't know.  If you remove the `;` after `RandomGraph[...]` so it gets a chance to be shown alone first, it'll work.  This smells like a bug, can you please report it to support at wolfram.com?

Comment: Here's a minimal example: `g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]; GraphEmbedding[g]; g`.

Comment: I shouldn't have said that it doesn't have a layout as the layout obviously gets computed by GraphEmbedding, what I meant is that the display of the graph looks the same as that of `RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> None]`.

Comment: Still there in 10.0.1

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Not a good news for us then :( Hope some other buggy things are repaired, that came along with the long awaited V 10.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

As commented by Szabolcs, this problem occurs as a result of preventing the rendering of the `Graph` by adding a semi-colon to the end of the `RandomGraph` expression. This is obviously a bug.

Using the built-in `ConvexHullMesh` and allowing the graph to render:

```
g = RandomGraph[{12, 18}]
pt = GraphEmbedding[g];
chull = ConvexHullMesh[pt];
```

Then:

```
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Style[1, Thin, Green]], g, Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point[pt]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This does *not* seem to solve OP's problem [in *version 10*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdUYO.png) on my machine.

Comment: @Silvia, Well, I'm on Windows 8.1 and it works just fine as my answer shows.

Comment: I'm on win8.1 x64 and mma 10.0 too... Now this is really getting strange...

Comment: @Silvia, you're right. It seems like the bug occurs if you put the semi-colon after the `RandomGraph` expression.

Comment: Agree this is a bug (and a weird one)..

Comment: @RunnyKine Actually before posting this I have checked, without the `;` as you have done works in my machine with win 8.1 and MMA 10. I also think this is a bug. Very annoying actually as this was my first few lines of code while trying version 10 for the first time :(

Comment: @PlatoManiac, sorry to hear you had such an unpleasant experience with it. I assure you, other than a few (okay, more than a few) bugs we've discovered here, **V10** is actually so much fun to use :)

Comment: @RunnyKine I totally agree. That :( was meant to describe my mood six hours ago...As the hours passed by I am enjoying my time with the new characters of V10...lots of new functionalities to catch up with :)

Comment: @PlatoManiac, good to hear :)

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56160/mathematica-10-graph-issue#comment161233_56160), I found adding following line after `g = RandomGraph[{12, 18}];` will make things right on my 10.0:

```
PrintTemporary[g];
```

Or

```
CopyToClipboard[g];
```

I guess any command that makes the FrontEnd rendering `g`.

Comment: other workaround: Show[g = RandomGraph[{12, 18}]];
pt = GraphEmbedding[g];
g

Comment: @halmir Why I didn't think of that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 10.0.2. On windows 7, 64 bit

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
g = RandomGraph[{12, 18}];
pt = GraphEmbedding[g];
convexhull = ConvexHull[pt];
Show[PlanarGraphPlot[pt, convexhull, ColorOutput -> Red], g, 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, Point[#]} & /@ pt]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]; GraphEmbedding[g]; g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]