# Writing a procedure that invokes Manipulate[]

Tags: plotting, manipulate, scoping

I would like to write a procedure with the signature:

```
Foo[vars, params]
```

which produces a `Manipulate` object. The procedure will dress up the `vars` into sliders of the form:

```
{{a, a0, "DisplayName"}, min, max, Appearance->"Labeled"}
```

and will produce a `Plot`, depending on both the `params` and `vars`. (The default value `a0` and the other slider properties are generated in a particular manner from `a`.)

The issue I'm running into is that `Manipulate` requires all of its `vars` to be explicitly listed. I looked at the related question [Proper way to handle free variables in manipulate/plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/proper-way-to-handle-free-variables-in-manipulate-plot) to no avail (I couldn't get `With` to do what I want).

So how does one procedurally generate the commands of `Manipulate`? I am constrained to use `Manipulate` as opposed to `Dynamic` or other more advanced features.

---

**Concrete Example:**

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[
        c0 + c1 x + c2 x^2,
        {x,0,1}
    ],
    {{c0, 0},-1, 1},
    {{c1, 1}, 0, 2},
    {{c2, 2}, 1, 3},
]
```

Then the goal would be to replace the 2 with an n, i.e. to write a function `Poly[n]` which returns a manipulatable polynomial with coefficients `c_i` centered around i.

Comment: "The default value a0 and the other slider properties are generated in a particular manner from a."  This is quite vague.  Without some idea of what you need it is hard to provide a recommendation.

Comment: Okay I'll write up a more concrete mwe.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to do what you want. i.e. call a function to generate the controls, since the controls have to be set before evaluation. The closest you can do, is use `With` to help reduce duplicate code. Please see [injecting-list-of-controls-into-manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66414/injecting-list-of-controls-into-manipulate) which is pretty much asking the same thing, and the discussion and links there.

Comment: @pre-kidney Please see the linked Q&A in Nasser's comment; do you think this question is a duplicate of that one, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please tell me if this does what you want:

```
poly[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 {
   Array[{{\[FormalC][#], #}, # - 1, # + 1} &, n + 1, 0],
   Sum[\[FormalC][i] \[FormalX]^i, {i, 0, n}]
 } /. {{var__}, expr_} :>
        Manipulate[Plot[expr, {\[FormalX], 0, 1}], var]

poly[4]
```

[image]

Comment: This approach seems like it will work well for me, but I'm running into a couple hurdles. First of all, my Plot function relies on several other procedures, and I am having issues porting it to work with your code. I will add it to an edit of the question.

Comment: I thought I understood the `foo /. bar :> baz` construction but after some fiddling it appears I was mistaken. Is it the `bar :> baz` that specifies the lazy replacement rule, which is then applied to `foo`?

Comment: The Manipulate is continuously running. I am on V 10.02. typing `poly[4]` shows the right side is solid black all the time, which means it is running all the time. To see this more clearly, I added `DateString[]` call, `poly[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 {Array[{{\[FormalC][#], #}, # - 1, # + 1} &, n + 1, 0], Sum[\[FormalC][i] \[FormalX]^i, {i, 0, n}]} /. {{var__}, expr_} :> 
   Manipulate[Row[{DateString[], Plot[expr, {\[FormalX], 0, 1}]}], var]
` and the clock is updating all the time.

Comment: @pre-kidney I'm heading for bed so I'll have to address the update tomorrow.  Regarding the second point please see [(1937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) and [(8399)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) which hopefully give a foundation for my use of replacement here.  If not I'll try to explain tomorrow.

Comment: @Nasser I hadn't noticed.  I'll explore *that* tomorrow too.

Comment: Thank you both for your extensive help today. It has been wonderful learning more about Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser It seems the constant updating is due to the use of `\[FormalX]` in `Plot`, but I'm not going further tonight.

Comment: `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate` keeps the tracking confined to the `vars`.  No further explanation at this point.

Comment: This causes continual updating: `Protect[y]; Dynamic[{Block[{y = 1}, y], Block[{y = 2}, y]}]`.  Perhaps it's the clearing of the `Attributes` by `Block`?

Comment: Any workarounds?

Comment: @pre-kidney Adding the option `TrackedSymbols :> Manipulate` to `Manipulate` is a workaround. So is `Manipulate[Block[{\[FormalX]}, Plot[expr, {\[FormalX], 0, 1}]], var]`.  But maybe someone will figure out a more elegant one.

Comment: @pre-kidney I've been busy today.  The code from the [first version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/72853/1) of my answer with manual `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` does not seem to have that problem.  I intend to come back to this but I don't have time now.  Sorry.

Comment: Your first revision appears to solve my problem better. At the moment, I am fine with littering my code with `Hold`s all over the place, so it looks like I will use that version. Thanks!